# How to write the application insights telemetry data into local database

Tags: uwp, azure-application-insights

I want to write the application insights telemetry data into local database/file using Application insights SDK in UWP application. Once written into the local file/database then i have to read the data to AZURE for some reason.

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks
Sekar

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) feature of Application Insights.
It exports everything continuously to a Blob Storage and from there you can do your post processing either in Azure or downloading it to some local storage.

If you need to save it locally before sending it to Azure you could implement your logic in a [Custom Telemetry Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling).

Hope that helps,
Andreas